# getting data from firebase using swift

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

there is a model and a function for loading data and a model for identifying data, there is also a model for receiving data, but an error occurs, there is no document or there is no collection. when adding an existing collection and document, everything works, please help me figure out where the error is. I want to make reviews, recording works, but reading reviews does not.

function for writing data to firebase:

```
func setStarts_review(order: Starts_review, completion: @escaping(Result<Starts_review, Error>) -> ()) {
    usersRefStartsReview.document(order.title).collection(order.userID).document(order.id).setData(order.representation) {
        error in if let error = error {
            completion(.failure(error))
        }else {
           
                    completion(.success(order))
                    
                }
            }
            
        }
```

a model for identifying recorded data:

struct Starts_review: Identifiable {

```
var id: String 
var userID: String
var date: Date
var starts_review: Int
var review: String
var title: String
var city: String





var representation: [String: Any]{

    var repres = [String: Any]()

    repres["starts_review"] = self.starts_review
    repres["review"] = self.review

    repres["userID"] = userID

    repres["date"] = Timestamp(date: date)
    repres["id"] = self.id
    repres["nameStart"] = self.title

    repres["StartCity"] = self.city


    return repres

}
```

}

a model for getting data from firebase:

import SwiftUI
import Firebase

class getDataReviewStarts : ObservableObject{

```
@Published var datasReview = [Starts_review]()


private var ViewModelNewReg: Starts_review {
    return Starts_review(id: "", userID: AuthService.shared.currentUser!.uid, date: Date(), starts_review: 0, review: "", title: "", city: "")
}


@Published var ViewModelNewRegReview = Starts_review(id: "", userID: AuthService.shared.currentUser!.uid, date: Date(), starts_review: 0, review: "gdgdfghfh", title: "", city: "")

@Published var reviewStarts: Starts_review

init(reviewStarts: Starts_review) {
    self.reviewStarts = reviewStarts

    let db = Firestore.firestore()

    db.collection("Starts_Review").document(ViewModelNewReg.title).collection(ViewModelNewReg.userID).getDocuments { (snap, err) in

        if err != nil{

            print((err?.localizedDescription)!)
            return
        }

        for i in snap!.documents{

            let id = i.documentID
            let titleReview = i.get("nameStart") as! String

            let cityReview = i.get("StartCity") as! String
            let userIDReview = AuthService.shared.currentUser!.uid

            let starts_review_Review = i.get("starts_review") as! Int
            let review_Review = i.get("review") as! String


            self.datasReview.append(Starts_review(id: id, userID: userIDReview, date: Date(), starts_review: starts_review_Review, review: review_Review, title: titleReview, city: cityReview))
        }
    }
}
```

}

I tried to make static data, they work, dynamics does not work

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by static works but dynamic doesn't.

Comment: by static, I mean the data that I directly enter, that is, the name of the collection and the name of the document. and by dynamics, I understand that I get the name of the collection and the name of the document automatically from the user and substitute them into the function of getting data from the database